# c++ sort vector of pointers error

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, vector, runtime-error

I have a vector vec that I need to sort every time I put an element inside it

so when I put the first Upgrade* inside the vector I have no problems

but when I put the second Upgrade* inside it and the sort routine is called I have a runtime error

this is how I put elements and call sort every time I insert

```
std::vector<Upgrade*> stack = getStack();

stack.push_back(element);

std::sort(stack.begin(), stack.end(), CostBenefitUpgradeOrder());
```

and this is my comparator

```
struct CostBenefitUpgradeOrder {
    bool operator ()(const Upgrade * u1, const Upgrade * u2) const {

        const UpgradeType upgradeType1 = u1->getUpgradeType();
        const UpgradeType upgradeType2 = u2->getUpgradeType();

        int price1 = PriceUtil::getPrice(upgradeType1);
        int price2 = PriceUtil::getPrice(upgradeType2);

        if (price2 < price1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the error

[image: runtime error]

**I have noticed that it only happens when I execute the program in Debug mode!!**

Comment: Your comparison is broken.  It needs to adhere to strict weak ordering standards.  This means if (x < y) is true, then (y < x) must be false.

Comment: Not sure why you did the sort comparison the way you did.  Please see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: So, for testing replace the comparison with return u1 < u2; [which is a valid sort] and see if you still crash

Comment: guys.. I just put this `return true` for debugging.. the real code has the verifications returning true and false

Comment: Yes - but it's likely the debug library build has a check that the comparator is valid - ie is a strict weak ordering. The assert message  even hints at this `invalid operator<`.

Comment: Well, if you don't post your real code you can't expect a real answer.  Either way, if you are seeing that assertion fail then your comparison is still broken.

Comment: i'll edit the question and put the code for you to see

Comment: thats ok! there is the code above!

Comment: another question, why the parameters of the operator() must be const?

Comment: Still not a strict weak ordering, replace with return price2 < price1

Comment: I'm very confused.  Is the question no longer valid because it's been updated with the answer?

Comment: Note that once your comparator is fixed, you can insert while keeping the vector sorted in one shot using: `stack.insert( upper_bound( stack.begin(), stack.end(), element, CostBenefitUpgradeOrder()), element);`  Keep in mind that sorting something that is already mostly sorted can sometimes result in poor behavior by some sort algorithms (though I imagine that most C++ library implementations deal with this in a reasonable way). Also, `stack` seems to be a misleading name for this thing which doesn't really appear to be a stack.

Comment: guys.. I have noticed that it only happens when I execute the program in Debug mode.. =\ this makes any sense for you?

Comment: @thiagoh: it only happens in debug builds because assertions and debug checking is disabled in release builds. However the bug still exists in release builds, it's just that you might not notice it for every set of data.

Comment: @MichaelBurr how can I disable this check in debug mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comparison function is broken. You cannot have a predicate that returns `true` for both `u1 < u2` and `u2 < u1`.

Replace the return statement with `return u1 < u2;` if you just need something for a quick test.

Also, are you sure you need to use a `vector`? Unless you need the pointers to be stored in contiguous memory, you'd be better off using an `std::set` instead with an appropriate comparator. The `set` will keep the elements ordered after every insertion / deletion.

Also, since you're using raw pointers, if you're allocating the objects using `new` make sure you `delete` before removing elements from the container. Better yet, use an `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Upgrade>, CostBenefitUpgradeOrder>` instead and not have to worry about deleting the allocated memory.

Comment: another question, why the parameters of the operator() must be const?

Comment: @thiagoh Because the comparator should not mutate the objects being compared

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass "strict weak ordering" (less than) operator to the  `std::sort` method, and that operator must be "valid".

Valid operator< have the following properties:

- For all [image: x], it is not the case that [image: x] < [image: x] (irreflexivity). For all [image: x],
- [image: y], if [image: x] < [image: y] then it is not the case that y < x (asymmetric). For all
- [image: x], [image: y], and [image: z], if [image: x] < [image: y] and [image: y] < [image: z] then [image: x] < [image: z] (transitivity). For all [image: x],
- [image: y], and [image: z], if [image: x] is incomparable with [image: y], and [image: y] is incomparable with [image: z], then [image: x] is incomparable with [image: z] (transitivity of incomparability).

You can see that your operator fails on the first point (`CostBenefitUpgradeOrder(x, x) == true`, in your case) (and on most other points, as well).

Comment: another question, why the parameters of the operator() must be const?

Comment: Because you should not try to modify the object data to determine if it's 'less than' other